# mmap(), where does the memory reside in virtual space?

Tags: c, unix, mmap, virtual-memory

I'm a bit confused about the `mmap()` system call. I realize that it maps memory, what I don't understand is how calling the `mmap()` call *from the application* interferes *(or not)* with the already running malloced segments, specifically those segments allocated using `sbrk()`.

Let me explain more what I'm getting at: 
Suppose I allocated several structures through the simple `malloc(x);` where `x < 1MB`. According to glibc these calls will be satisfied using sbrk() call (v2.15/malloc.c), which will grow the data segment upward.

`sbrk()` will cause the virtual data segment to grow **contiguously**. So my question is, what happens when `sbrk()` is called into a memory region that was allocated through `mmap()`.

Any thoughts or comments on this?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried some experiments on 64-bit OS X (Mountain Lion). The `sbrk` and `mmap` documentation do not refer to each other, so some of this is reading between the lines, but it looks like:

- There is a large area reserved for `sbrk` to grow into. When you exceed that reservation, `sbrk` will fail.
- When `mmap` is allowed to choose the location for a map (it is called without the `MAP_FIXED` flag), it chooses areas other than the reservation for `sbrk`.
- So, in normal use, `sbrk` and `mmap` do not interfere with each other. Furthermore, whichever implementation `malloc` uses, it should accept the memory it gets and incorporate it into its database without problem, whether it gets that memory from `sbrk` or from `mmap` or from elsewhere. And it should not interfere with the program’s independent normal use of `sbrk` and `mmap`.
- If you call `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` and specify an address that is in the reserved area of `sbrk`, then `mmap` will map memory there.
- If you continue to call `sbrk` after a `mmap` as described above, `sbrk` will return success even though the new break address overlaps memory mapped with `mmap`. At this point, your program is likely broken.

Thus, it is unwise to use `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` unless you have good reason to know the address you specify is okay.

Answer (score 1):

The simple division between heap and stack is a simplification. A modern operating system supports a large *virtual* address space with many independent memory areas visible to a process. Although these areas are part of the same address space, they are not contiguous, they have holes in it. The addresses `mmap()` returns is in one of the many holes: it could be between the heap and the stack, after the stack, before the heap—it doesn't make a difference as long as those regions never meet.

Remember also that in a threaded program there is no *single* stack, there are as many of those as there are threads.

Comment: So I'm aware of the different segments and the thread stacks, but as far as the process is concerned, it's just one contiguous space. Same with the allocator, it only sees the memory it extended with brk and the memory it mapped, my question is though, how do either know that user mmaped memory is running into allocator's heap memory?

Comment: Sorry to add on to this; somebody has to determine, that the dynamic segment is growing into a mmaped segment? I can see that the operating system could be aware of that, but is malloc() aware of that, I didn't think so but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @user2246674; so is that the answer then? We just have to trust it that the (user) mmaped region will simply not interfere with the growing heap/stack?

Comment: @janjust: `malloc` is not necessarily implemented to call `mmap` to get more memory, but let us suppose it is. When `malloc` calls `mmap` to get more memory, `mmap` returns an address to the new memory. `malloc` does not care if this is consecutive with its previous memory or not. It does not maintain memory as a simple single segment. It has a complicated database, and it simply records the new space in its database. Furthermore, when `mmap` decides where to put the new space, it consults data about the process’ address space so far and chooses an unused place.

Comment: @janjust: (Note that `mmap` can also be given an address for the new map rather than allowed to choose for itself. In that case, it simply determines whether the requested space overlaps previous maps or not. If it overlaps, an error is returned, and no new map is created. If it does not overlap, the new map is recorded in the data about the process.)

Comment: @janjust: Also, `brk` is archaic. If something is still using it, I expect it will work until it bumps into space that is mapped for some other reason. At that point, it should return an error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29002/discussion-between-janjust-and-eric-postpischil)

Comment: @janjust *So I'm aware of the different segments and the thread stacks, but as far as the process is concerned, it's just one **contiguous** space.* This is the source of your confusion. It is one space, but it's not contiguous, it can (and does) have holes in it.

Comment: @Jim, I'm not trying to "tell" anyone anything, trying to understand ;) Please, let's go to the chat if possible, comments are long enough as is.

Comment: @janjust StackOverflow is about providing answers to concrete questions. Your question seems to be written under the incorrect assumption that virtual address space is contiguously allocated. Once that confusion is dispelled, it is unclear what you are now asking.